# Javascript: function working sometimes, and other times just not doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I'm really confused about this but I'm sure there's an explanation. I'm working on a personal training webapp and I have a timer that, every time it reaches `00:00`, it should go to `00:10` and stop. The timer works using this function I wrote:

```js
//timer object function
function Timer(element, callback) {

  var ac, minutes, seconds, finalTimeInSeconds, displayMinutes, displaySeconds, interval = 1000,
    self = this,
    timeLeftToNextSecond = 1000,
    running = false;

  this.set = function(inputMinutes, inputSeconds) {

    finalTimeInSeconds = inputMinutes * 60 + inputSeconds;
    minutes = (Math.floor(finalTimeInSeconds / 60));
    seconds = finalTimeInSeconds % 60;

    this.print();
  }

  this.add = function(inputMinutes, inputSeconds) {

    finalTimeInSeconds += inputMinutes * 60 + inputSeconds;
    finalTimeInSeconds = (finalTimeInSeconds < 0) ? 0 : finalTimeInSeconds;
    minutes = (Math.floor(finalTimeInSeconds / 60));
    seconds = finalTimeInSeconds % 60;

    this.print();
  }

  this.subtract = function(inputMinutes, inputSeconds) {

    finalTimeInSeconds -= inputMinutes * 60 + inputSeconds;
    if (finalTimeInSeconds < 0) {
      callback()
    }
    finalTimeInSeconds = (finalTimeInSeconds < 0) ? 0 : finalTimeInSeconds;
    minutes = (Math.floor(finalTimeInSeconds / 60));
    seconds = finalTimeInSeconds % 60;
    this.print();
  }

  this.reset = function() {

    this.set(0, 0);
  }

  this.print = function() {

    displayMinutes = (minutes.toString().length == 1) ? "0" + minutes : minutes; //ternary operator: adds a zero to the beggining 
    displaySeconds = (seconds.toString().length == 1) ? "0" + seconds : seconds; //of the number if it has only one caracter.

    $(element).text(displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds);
  }

  this.run = function() {

    if (running == false) {
      running = true;

      var _f = function() {
        secondStarted = new Date;
        self.subtract(0, 1);
        interval = 1000;

        ac = setTimeout(_f, interval);


      }
      ac = setTimeout(_f, interval);


    }
  }

  this.stop = function() {

    if (running == true) {
      running = false;
      console.log(this + "(" + element + ") was stopped");
      stopped = new Date;
      interval = 1000 - (stopped - secondStarted);
      clearTimeout(ac);
    }
  }

  this.getTotalTimeInSeconds = function() {


    return finalTimeInSeconds;
  }

  this.reset();

}
```

What I did was create a timer like this:

```
globalTimer = new Timer("#globalTimer", function() {
            globalTimer.stop();
            globalTimer.set(0,10);
        });
```

And then I set it to `00:15` and ran it:

```
globalTimer.set(0,15);
globalTimer.run();
```

And for some reason, when the timer reaches zero, it sets to `00:10`, but it doesn't stop. The thing is, before it reaches `00:00`, I can stop it with the console and it works perfectly; but when the timer gets to zero the `.stop()` function just doesn't work anymore. Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/JocaPinto/dnavrw6e/) for a demo I made. Why does this happen? Is there something wrong with the `Timer` function? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a simple check to your 'running' variable in your setTimeout callback function should be enough here. I think you may possibly be getting slightly confused with the difference between setTimeout and setInterval.

I simply removed the clearTimeout from your 'stop' function as it wasn't required and changed your 'run' function to check if your 'globalTimer' was 'running' and it worked as you described.

```
this.run = function() 
{
    var _f = function() {
        secondStarted = new Date;
        self.subtract(0, 1);
        interval = 1000;

        var theColorIs = $(element).css("color");
        if (running == true)
        {
            ac = setTimeout(_f, interval);
        }
    }

    if (running == false) 
    {
        running = true;
        ac = setTimeout(_f, interval);
    }
}
```

Comment: But why doesn't my code stop the timer when it reaches zero, but it does change the `running` var? That's what's not making sense to me.

Comment: This is due to you firing off another setTimeout callback when the previous callback completes. `clearTimeout` only removes (clears) the delay from the setTimeout callback function and does not stop/disable it's execution. Using the `running` variable here bypasses this loop chain.

For an example on setTimeout check out... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout

Comment: I wound up going with a setInterval function and it works perfectly, but your answer helped me reach that, and helped with the frustration this was making me feel so thanks so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the variable `running` is still set to false,
 just add the following line after closing the if statement in the stop function.

```
running = true;
```

Here is the code extract.

```
this.stop = function() {
    if (running == true) {
        running = false;
        console.log(this + "(" + element + ") was stopped");
        stopped = new Date;
        interval = 1000 - (stopped - secondStarted);
        clearTimeout(ac);
    }
    running = true;
}
```

Comment: but I want the `running` to be false while the timer is stopped, otherwise there would be no point in having the variable.

Comment: Your stop function() will ONLY run if the running variable is set to true, when the function execute the variable is set to false and it will remain that way through  out the entire code that's the reason why you should reset it to true after that code in the function execute so that when the function is called again after it reaches 00.00 again the if statement condition can check to true. You can try to alert the value of running variable before the if ie alert(running);if(... to see what is its value.

Comment: I have checked your code and sure the variable is not mandatory since it is the only one function using it but if its value depended on an another function like set() which will only be for semantic purpose ie the stop function which stops wont be the same setting the value to running but in functionality it is the same.